# How to change the email subject in jhipster?

Tags: java, thymeleaf, jhipster

I am using Jhipster for my application.I want to send emails where i need to set user defined subject. Is it possible?

```
 String subject = messageSource.getMessage("user defined subject", null, locale);
```

I tried with this method.But its returning error in locale not found " user defined subject". Please help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of `messageSource.getMessage` method is a key that must exist in a properties file in `src/main/resources/i18n`. You passed a string "user defined subject" which is your subject, you must pass a key and define the subject in the properties files matching this key.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I modifed the email service to `  sendEmail(email, emailDTO.getSubject(), content, false, true);`  It worked